# How to add labels to shapefile point layer in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, plot

I have plotted a shapefile containing points in R, and I would like to add labels like : point 1, point 2 and so on..) to the plot.

Is this possible?

Comment: Here is a solution using `ggplot2`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22038640/1446289

Comment: Use text(x, labels = x$columname)

Comment: thanks, that worked fine. Any suggestons to how I can adjust the position of the labels. Right now I have the id numbers of the points right on top of the cross-marker of the points, making it difficult to see.

Comment: I figured it out. Added argument "pos" = 1,2,3 or 4 does the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a simple reproducible example below:

```
# Libraries for GIS
library('sp')

# Library for plot
library('latticeExtra')

# Load data ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Points
x <- c(1199999, 1080000, 1093067, 1090190, 1087977, 1070419, 1180419)
y <- c(957803,937803, 894366, 872153, 853703, 825353, 805353)

# Create SpatialPoints
SP <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y))

# Add label variable
SP$ID <- paste("point", 1:7, sep = "")

# Plot
plot <- spplot(SP, zcol = "ID")
labels <- layer(sp.text(coordinates(SP), txt = SP$ID, pos = 1))

# plot + label layer
plot + labels
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 4):

For base graphics, use `pointLabel` from `maptools` package.

Using this data:

```
x <- c(1199999, 1080000, 1093067, 1090190, 1087977, 1070419, 1180419)
y <- c(957803,937803, 894366, 872153, 853703, 825353, 805353)
```

Add another point close to point 4:

```
library(sp)
x = c(x,x[4]+1000)
y = c(y,y[4])
SP <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x,y))
SP$ID <- paste("point", 1:length(SP), sep = "")
```

Plot points, add labels:

```
library(maptools)
plot(SP)
pointLabel(coordinates(SP),labels=SP$ID)
```

[image]

Note point4 and point8 labels don't overlap.